# div opens on new page instead of staying on map page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am trying to display my input form buttons on the right side outside of my map after I have created a marker with the L.draw plugin. However if I click on the created marker, the form buttons open on a new page instead of staying on the page where the map is. Here is my code:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e){
  var type = e.layerType;
  layer = e.layer;
  var marker_y = layer.getLatLng().lat;
  var marker_x = layer.getLatLng().lng;

var marker = drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

marker.on('click', function (e){

  document.getElementById('i').innerHTML = 

'<form role="form" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class ="form-horizontal" >'+ 
'<h1>Beschreibung</h1>' +
'<label>text <input type="text" name="text" id="text"></label>' + '<br/>'  +
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="ok">Add to Database</button>'+
'</form>';

 });
```

The set up of my div looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div id="i">
 <div id="map">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried an `e.preventDefault();` right before the `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: Yes but I get this Error: `TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function`

Comment: But have you used `()`? Like in `e.preventDefault()`, and not just `e.preventDefault()`???

Comment: Yes. I did use ( ).

Comment: Then check, please, what kind of object is `e`. With a simple `console.log(e)`, so we can see what is the best way to solve this.

Comment: e is: `Object { layer: Object, target: Object, originalEvent: click, latlng: Object, type: "click" }`

Comment: Would you please close the two divs in your HTML code correctly and try again? I don't think it will solve your problem, but when you are trying to find an error it is not good to have other errors around to make you confused. Divs `infobox` and `map` are not correctly closed with a `</div>` tag.

Comment: Is your issue when clicking on a marker or when clicking on the form submit button?

Comment: The issue occurs if I click on the marker.